# Convert variable values from VB6 to C# in order to work with Win32

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a series of values from some VB6 code I found [online](http://groups.google.com/groups?hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&selm=9m116e%24beglg%241%40ID-24932.news.dfncis.de).  I need this code converted to C#.  I have no idea how to read VB6.  How can I convert this VB6 to the equivalent C#?

```
Private Const EM_GETRECT = &HB2;
Private Const EM_SETRECT = &HB3
Private Const EM_SCROLLCARET = &HB7

Private Const ES_AUTOHSCROLL = &H80&
Private Const ES_AUTOVSCROLL = &H40&
Private Const ES_CENTER = &H1&
```

Judging by one signature

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

that takes these types of variables (as the Msg param), I believe these should be of the form

`const int EM_GETRECT =`

I don't know how to change the `&HB2` to an int.  I think it'll be `0x???`, but how do I convert this little `&HB2` to hex?

Comment: @Steve - That pattern appears appropriate for the first 3.  What about the last 3 that end in `&`?

Comment: &HB2 - is a hex code. &H means hex for... So the C# equivelant would be 0xB2. You nearly got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax to express an hexdecimal value in C# is simply 0x followed by the hex representation of the number. (And this representation is the same in VB6 and C#) so you write

```
private const int EM_GETRECT = 0xB2;
Console.WriteLine(EM_GETRECT);
```

prints out 178 decimal.

The last three values (with the & suffix) are VB variables of long datatype.
In C# the datatype int is the same as VB long. 
You could still use a C# integer

```
private const int ES_CENTER = 0x1; 
Console.WriteLine(ES_CENTER);
```

prints 1 as expected

Answer (score 3):

It's just indicating the number is read out in long integer, formatted as hex. (after the H)

You can just use these values if you want:

```
const int EM_GETRECT = 0xB2;
const int EM_SETRECT = 0xB3;
const int EM_SCROLLCARET = 0xB7;

const int ES_AUTOHSCROLL = 0x80;
const int ES_AUTOVSCROLL = 0x40;
const int ES_CENTER = 0x1;
```